# Postgresql function to return table with change

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I get an error in a function call.  The error is:

> column reference "rental" is ambiguous LINE 2: CASE active DETAIL: It
> could refer to either a PL/PGSQL variable or a  table column

The query is:

```
CREATE FUNCTION convert()
RETURNS TABLE (customerid int, fname varchar, lname varchar, email varchar, tripDate timestamp, rental varchar)
Language plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
     RETURN QUERY
            SELECT CASE WHEN rental = 1 
                        THEN 'yes'
                        ELSE 'no'
             END
     FROM EML
END; $$;
```

Comment: [CASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE), there is no `END`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
SELECT CASE WHEN rental = 1 THEN 'yes'
                        WHEN rental = 0 THEN 'no'
```

to

```
SELECT 
    CASE 
        WHEN rental = 1 
            THEN 'yes'
         ELSE  'no'
END
```

edit section:

if you wan't iterate just binary value, you should be add this condition like this:

```
RETURN QUERY
         SELECT 
        CASE 
            WHEN rental = 1 
                THEN 'yes'
             ELSE  'no'
    END
 FROM EML WHERE rental In(0, 1)
```

Comment: I agree, there's an else needed here.  but would that not assume all other values must be `'no'`?  what if the value is '3', 'yes', 'cookie?'

Comment: what do you need for non binary values?

Comment: @arcee123 see edit section.

Comment: @arcee123 in the rental column there are only 1's and 0's that I would like to use this function to redisplay the table changing that column type from int to varchar and returning Yes or No.  The above is still throwing a syntax error.  Knowing that I am changing the Datatype in the output do I need to use the alter table command first?

Comment: what is the data type for the rental field?  I get the 1/0 thing, but if we are dealing with bit vs byte vs smallest, then I can see why the error.

Comment: arcee123  The data type for rental in existing table is int ( either 1, or 0)
but want to change them to Yes or No